# A question about the Leray-Serre spectral sequence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Suppose $F \to E \stackrel{p}{\to} B$ is a fibration with $B$ simply connected. The $E_2^{p,q}$ page of the Leray-Serre spectral sequence is given by $H^p(B;H^q(F))$. Suppose futhermore that $k$ is a field and we would like to consider the cohomology of $E$ with coefficients in $k$. We clearly have
$$
 E_2^{p,q} = H^p(B;k)\otimes_k H^q(F;k).
$$
Now suppose $E_2^{p,q}=E_\infty^{p,q}$ for a fixed pair $(p,q)$ such that $p\neq 0$ and $q \neq 0$. Is there any way to identify $H^p(B;k)\otimes_k H^q(F;k)$ in $H^{p+q}(E;k)$?

I am aware that in case of $q=0$, $H^p(B;k)$ can be identified via $p^*$ in $H^{p}(E;k)$.

Comment: The spectral sequence gives a filtration on $H^r(E;k)$, and $E^{p,q}_\infty$ is one of the associated subquotient vector spaces.  I am aware of no canonical splitting of that filtration (there are abutment maps).

Comment: Correction: "abutment map" --> "edge map".

Comment: Almost certainly not: even if the spectral sequence collapses at $E_2$, that doesn't imply that $\oplus_p H^p(B, k) \otimes_k H^{n-p}(F, k)$ is isomorphic to $H^n(E, k)$: there are in principal additive an multiplicative extensions that could be nontrivial.  If there were the sort of identification that you seek, these extensions would be trivial by force.

Comment: The Milnor hypersurfaces give a nice example of the phenomenon that @CraigWesterland mentioned.  This is Example 3.3 in my notes at http://www.shef.ac.uk/nps/courses/bestiary/ss.pdf